# Create a folder in WCF hosted by Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I've got a big problem with create a folder in a WCF application running under Asp.net

Do following steps !

1. Create Asp.net MVC project -> **Done**
2. Create a WCF service inside asp.net MVC project ->**Done**
3. Inside WCF, create a method (i just want to create a folder inside this method) named CreateFolder() ->**Done - it's works**

This is code inside method created :

```
var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UserData");
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Well, it's doesn't work !

Now, try again with another code !

```
var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/YourDirectory");
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Again, it' doesn't work too.

PS: it's only works on Local machine PC.
When i published asp.net Website and upload to my hosting, everything good except above method(create folder)

Any idea ?

PPS: I just want to create Folder for user registered !

Comment: **Permissions**. Check with your hosting provider on how you can grant your **application** privileges such as creating folders. It "works" locally when you debug because things run in _your user context_. Hth.

Answer (score 1):

Test it with a direct path address, like "d:/UserData" instead of "~/UserData".

Comment: WCF hosted on asp.net hosting. 

Its path: "D:\\vhosts\\haitv.info\\ANNOUNCE_ME\\UserDatas"

But i can't create folder in code behind.

Comment: Is that host server yours? if you can change permissions, so you can do some works with iis, your application and your application pool.

Comment: Nothing to say if i work with IIS on Local Machine and my Application Pool.

I just want to public my Application (WCF) to the host and use it !
Because my windows phone application will upload a file to the server(running wcf). and i have no idea because of this problem

Comment: In fact my question is about call it from client. Does your application work when you publish it on your local server, and use it from another computer (in different domain)?

Comment: Ohh yes, problem solved.  IIS local and hosting invironment are different. Just Create a virtual directory on Host and grant its permission read and write :)

nicely done !